# php-cli error when using full path

Tags: php, mysql

i'm using php 5.6 on ubuntu but when i run a the command php /var/www/html/export-sftp-bg.php i get

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'File  doesn't exist' in /var/www/html/inc/vendor/faisalman/simple-excel-php/src/SimpleExcel/Parser/BaseParser.php:174
>   Stack trace:
>
> 0 /var/www/html/inc/vendor/faisalman/simple-excel-php/src/SimpleExcel/Parser/CSVParser.php(38): SimpleExcel\Parser\BaseParser->isFileReady(false)
>
> 1 /var/www/html/inc/functions.php(1448): SimpleExcel\Parser\CSVParser->loadFile(false)
>
> 2 /var/www/html/export-sftp-bg.php(10): export_existing_campaign('Yml=', Object(SimpleExcel\SimpleExcel), Object(NotORM), '/var/www/html/e...')
>
> 3 {main}
>     thrown in /var/www/html/inc/vendor/faisalman/simple-excel-php/src/SimpleExcel/Parser/BaseParser.php on line 174

but i'm able to run the file by using cd /var/www/html
then php export-sftp-bg.php

Comment: My guess would be that the file path that `export-sftp-bg.php` is trying to convert is relative.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo -u www-data php /var/www/html/export-sftp-bg.php
```

Try to run the php as apache user in ubuntu from the comand line.

Change your file permissions
You should run script as root (not recommend) , or instead change the file permissions:

```
  sudo chown ubuntu:www-data file
  sudo chmod 664 file
```

And you should do nearly the same with the directory:

```
  sudo chown ubuntu:www-data -R dir
  sudo chmod 775 -R dir
```